# Calculating floating P&L of a FIX-order

Tags: market-data, fx, algorithmic-trading, fix, quickfix

How to fetch  floating p/l(current) of a "filled" FIX-Order (either buy/sell)?(by its FIX-ID/order ID)

I asked my FIX provider(Integral) & they said, there's no specific tag for that/not a standard FIX practice, but it can be calculated on my side.(via different methods)
Is there any way to calculate floating p/l of a fix-order?(against current market price)

Comment: Does rupweb's answer help you? If not, can you clarify your question?

Comment: his suggestion sounds legit, sir, still i'm open to more/shortcut ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIX is just the message protocol so the PnL for a filled order (an execution report) on your side by taking the price and volume of the execution report and a reference price when you get the execution report, then calculate your PnL...

Comment: Can you please form me any equation to calculate that,if possible?
Anyway thanks for your input.

Comment: This is really getting too basic for this site. Please try to solve this yourself.

Comment: @BobJansen ,Okay, i rest my case here :)

Answer (score 0):

So you are asking about what is usually called Unrealized P&L. There are multiple ways to do this. It can be as simple as rupweb points out, but there are some complications, for example when you have previous closed trades, or have multiple open trades at multiple prices. For some detailed information on this, including a formula you can just copy, check out [TT's FIX Adapter documentation](https://www.tradingtechnologies.com/help/fix-adapter-reference/pl-calculation-algorithm/understanding-pl-calculations/).